# Intergarting WhatsApp with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, whatsapp

I wanna make some app. it can be send message to WhatsApps
I'm using this package : https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API
and when I wanna to registration phone number,
there are some error the error said

```
Array ( 
[in] => 8999300*** 
[cc] => 62 
[id] => cr#a��{��� kso�!�� 
[lg] => id [lc] => ID 
[sim_mcc] => 510 
[sim_mnc] => 000 
[method] => sms 
[token] => 8e22c1d44f7a3d59ad3c085f1eaf75ca ) 
stdClass Object ( 
[login] => 628999300*** 
[status] => fail 
[reason] => old_version )
```

and then I try to change version manually in Constant.php (Inside package)
but I got the error again

```
[login] => 628999300***
[status] => fail 
[reason] => bad_token
```

Anyone know, or ever do this and success? Please give me some reference, thanks for answering, I'm sorry for bad English

Comment: Are you using paid version or free api?

Comment: Might wanna read [this](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/issues/2116)